# What tells quarks, electrons, etc. to move the way they do?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, particle-physics, fermions, leptons

I've recently had some interest piqued in physics, and this is one of the many questions that I have continuously found myself trying to figure out; what tells/told particles to go in the direction that they go/went?

From the smallest scale, how do they move? Is it all based on gravity, electromagnetic fields, strong, and weak forces, or is it just a combination of all, a recipe for that happens to come together in different ways?

Comment: What is the difference between your last two questions? They don’t seem like alternatives to me.

Comment: @G.Smith I guess that in a way, they are not.

Answer (score 2):

The so-called Standard Model explains the behavior of elementary particles, using a collection of 17 quantum fields interacting through 3 interactions (electromagnetic, weak nuclear, and strong nuclear). It can predict, for example, how two electrons scatter off each other, or how an electron and a positron can annihilate into two photons.

A separate theory, General Relativity, explains gravity.

Physicists continue to work on combining the two theories into a unified theory of all four forces.

Answer (score 1):

> What tells quarks, electrons, etc. to move the way they do?

Since the discovery of the electron and the existence of atoms, a large number of data have been gathered. There have been consecutive mathematical models to describe their interactions, not just their motion. These models are quantum mechanical and are not deterministic, i.e. an individual electron is not "told" by any deterministic equation to be in a special location with special energy and momentum.

What the quantum mechanical models tell the researchers,not the particles, is **the probability** if one measures many electrons under the same boundary conditions, that they will have  that energy and momentum, or be at that (x,y,z,t). At present it is the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) that can predict these probabilities, and it incorporates the three forces you measure in its setup.

Answer (score 0):

They move, interact, deform and reform depending on exchanges but energy can't be completely confined so they can never not move. This causes the activity.

Comment: This answer doesn’t appear to have much information in it. Exchanges of what? What does it mean to confine energy?

Comment: The other answers already address most of the points including interaction and annihilation for example. To be specific I mean exchanges of information. See how long you can hold your breath. That is a measurement of how long you can confine energy in that case.